# can't convert text data to json

Tags: json, django, python-3.x

I am trying to convert the following (json) string into a python data type:

```
data = "{'id': 26, 'photo': '/media/f082b5af-ad0.png', 'first_name': 'Islam', 'last_name': 'Mansour', 'email': 'islammansour06+8@gmail.com', 'city': 'Giza', 'cv': '/media/fbb61609-442.pdf', 'reference': 'Facebook', 'campaign': OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('name', 'javascript')]), 'status': 'Invitation Sent', 'user': None, 'at': '2020-01-20', 'time': '23:02:58.359179', 'technologies': [OrderedDict([('id', 46), ('name', 'Django'), ('category', OrderedDict([('id', 24), ('name', 'Framework'), ('_type', 'skill')]))])]}"
```

I am trying to convert it to JSON by using

> json.loads(data.replace("\'", "\""))

but I am having the following error

```
json.decoder.JSONDecoderError: Expecting value: line 1 column 219 (char 218)
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from to be in this format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously said, OrderedDict is not correct JSON. But this is correct python.

To fix it:

```
from collections import OrderedDict  # direct import because this is as this in your string
import json
jsonCorrect = json.dumps(eval(data))
json.loads(jsonCorrect)  # it works
```

Comment: why importing the OrderedDict here ?

Comment: Simply because the eval will run the data as it is some python code and return it. And that code invokes OrderedDict. Hence the comment in the provided solution. You can have a look at the docstring of eval.

Comment: My pleasure @IslamMansour

Comment: @IslamMansour Please be aware of the security concerns of running `eval` you should not use this unless you truly know the ramification of doing so.

Comment: Indeed @MattSeymour, but knowing the use case ... well ... no choice apparently. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your data is not valid json.

The main problem starts here: `[OrderedDict([('id', 46), ('name', 'Django'), ('category', OrderedDict([('id', 24), ('name', 'Framework'), ('_type', 'skill')]))])]}`. This looks like it is a string representaion of some python objects.

Below is a more friendly representation of your json data.

I have marked the problematic parts (with **) (basically everywhere there is a OrderedDict).

````
{
"id":26,
"photo":"/media/f082b5af-ad0.png",
"first_name":"Islam",
"last_name":"Mansour",
"email":"islammansour06+8@gmail.com",
"city":"Giza",
"cv":"/media/fbb61609-442.pdf",
"reference":"Facebook",
"campaign":**OrderedDict**([("id",
2), ("name", "javascript")]), "status":"Invitation Sent",
"user":None,
"at":"2020-01-20",
"time":"23:02:58.359179",
"technologies":[
**OrderedDict**([("id",
46),
("name",
"Django")
]("category", OrderedDict([("id", 24), ("name", "Framework"), ("_type", "skill")]))])]
}```

You could try making use of an [online json parser][1] which might give you some friendlier output. 


  [1]: http://json.parser.online.fr/
````

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are adding the `replace` call.  Should work with just the following:

```
json.loads(data)
```

You can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: Also, as @Matt Seymour mentioned, you do not have valid JSON.